# I have intalled magento2 into xampp server and i encountered with this error when i tried to run it locally

Tags: magento2, extensions

Vendor autoload is not found. Please run **'composer install'** under application root directory.

It asked me to install composer and when i attempted to do so,

it returned,
`C:\xampp\htdocs\develop\develop>composer` install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

**Problem 1**
    - The requested PHP extension ext-intl * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.

**Problem 2**
    - The requested PHP extension ext-xsl * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's xsl extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable `intl` and `xsl` extension from `php.ini` file from `C:\xampp\php\`
by removing the comment from extension lines.

like `extension=php_intl.dll` and `extension=php_xsl.dll` remove semicolon before this lines and then restart the Apache server.

Comment: could you pls help me magento 2 install error ::: Failed loading c:/wamp/bin/php/php7.1.10/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11.dll
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file